# Remove headers from HttpClient response

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing, dotnet-httpclient, webservice-client

I'm facing a problem when using HttpClient. The call works right and I get an answer but I can't get the content properly.

The function I wrote looks like this:

```
    public async Task<string> MakePostRequestAsync(string url, string data, CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        String res = String.Empty;

        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            HttpContent content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = getHeaders();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/xml");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "C#-AppNSP");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content, cancel);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Lanza excepción si no hay éxito

            res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(res))
            {
                throw new Exception("Error: " + response.StatusCode);
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
```

The response string I get is similar to this one:

```
HTTP/1.1 0 nullContent-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1263
Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2019 07:48:07 GMT
Connection: close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SeguimientoEnviosFechasResponse xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SeguimientoEnviosFechasResponse.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Error>0</Error>
    <MensajeError></MensajeError>
    <SeguimientoEnvioFecha>
        <!-- more XML here -->
    </SeguimientoEnvioFecha>
</SeguimientoEnviosFechasResponse>
```

This string includes headers for some reason, so when I try to deserialize it I get an error.

How can I remove this headers in the response string?

Comment: What do you mean by `Headers` in the response string?

Comment: First 4-5 lines: HTTP/1.1 ...... Connection: close. This part can't be parsed as XML.

Comment: Use this: `res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`

Comment: Same result. I had to remove "await" keyword. res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

Comment: You would have to load the data in a `XDocument` and then parse it. You can use`ReadAsStreamAsync` to read the stream into the `XmlDocument` :  `string content= res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

XDocument responseXml= XDocument.Load(content);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server returns headers in the response body. Would be good to fix this on a server side, if it's not possible you should extract body from the response:

```
        var xml = res.Substring(res.IndexOf("<?xml", StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

Comment: That's what I'm really doing. It looks like there's something wrong. I cannot fix server side code. Don't really know why headers are written inside body :S

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
using (var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream()) 
{
  using (var readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8)) 
  {
    Console.WriteLine (readStream.ReadToEnd ());
  }
}
```

Comment: What's response in this case? for HttpResponseMessage there is no such method GetResponseStream(). It could be response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync() but there is no benefit of using it (I belive).